# Python socket select.select. Using list of objects instead of connections

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

Typically using `select.select()` will require a list of connection objects to work like this:

`read, write, error = select(self.all_connections, [], [], 0.1)`

Say I have the below object:

```
class remoteDevice(object)

    def __init___(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection
```

I will create a list of remoteDevices before using select after accepting the connections and append them to a list:

```
conn  = socket.accept()
newDevice = remoteDevice(conn)
all_devices.append(newDevice)
```

Now `all_devices` will be  alist of multiple devices, and their connection object is given to each remote device.

Is there a way I can pass in `all_devices` into the select statement to iterate through the `connection` property of each `remoteDevice` object? Will I have to store the connection objects seperately just to use `select.select()`?

Comment: Well, Thanks for clearing it up, Its a shame! keeping it OO would be much neater!

Comment: @julivico: No, that's not right. `select()` will accept a sequence of custom objects that provide a `fileno()` method. Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.select)

Comment: @mhaeke: you are right. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [`select.select()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.select) documentation you can supply a sequence of objects that have a `fileno()` method. You can easily add that method to your class:

```
class RemoteDevice(object):
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection

    def fileno(self):
        return self.connection[0].fileno()
```

The `fileno()` method simply returns the file descriptor of the connection's socket object. Since you instantiate `RemoteDevice` with the return value of `socket.accept()`, this a tuple in which the first item is a `socket` object.

Comment: This worked great!, In my solution I had to return `self.connection.fileno()` rather than indexing the connection property. A reminder to anyone else also: When checking for data in read it will be the custom object and not just the connection object of which is returned. so to receive the data in `read` we must use `remoteDevice.connection.recv()`